# The ridge at LHC

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

One of the results obtained by LHC is the following diagram for p-Pb collisions:
[image]

I would like to understand what is actually depicted in the figure, what should we expect based on theoretical approach? what can explain the ridge?

Comment: Could you please add a source for this diagram?

Comment: Let me help here http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5482

Comment: you can just google "lhc ridge". look here: http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2012/oct/31/unexpected-ridge-seen-in-cms-collision-data-again

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3411/

Comment: One of the downvotes is mine. You need to put more effort in the question.

Comment: To put in my two cents on what @Kostya said: if you are asking potential answerers to go searching the web to find out what you are asking about, you haven't put enough of your own effort into the question. You want other people to do some work to find out if they are able or interested in helping you?

Comment: I passed on several places on the web but didn't felt satisfied with the answer I found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the day, the diagram shows the distribution in angular differences between pairs of charged particles produced in the collisions.

$\Delta \phi = \phi_1-\phi_2$ is the difference in [azimuthal angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinates) $\phi$ of those pairs.

$\Delta \eta = \eta_1 - \eta_2$ is the difference in [pseudorapidities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinates) $\eta$ of those pairs.

The $\phi$ and $\eta$ variables are commonly used in HEP do describe angles between particle momenta. The  $\Delta \phi \times \Delta \eta$ bin is roughly Lorentz-invariant element of the angular phase space. So counting how many particles are captured in a given bin, can provide us with some information about the way the colliding particles are structured.

- The read peak around $\Delta \phi \simeq \Delta \eta \simeq 0$ is made of the same-direction-flying particle pairs. In hadron collisions such correlations are well-known and are called "[jets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28particle_physics%29)".
- If you have an event with a jet, then, due to momentum conservation, a lot of particles are going to fly in the opposite direction. That is the reason to have another bump is around the values $\Delta \phi\simeq \pi$.
- Finally, all the fuss is about the "ridge" -- the excess of events with $\Delta \phi \simeq 0$ and $|\Delta \eta| \in [\sim 2,\sim 4]$
  on your graphs it is marked with a black arrow. This feature basically means that there are particles having close azimuthal angles $\phi$ but their "polar angles" $\theta$ are almost uncorrelated.

From the theoretical perspective, as far as I understand, this "ridge" phenomenon is quite well understood in ion-ion collisions by means of some hydrodynamic descriptions. Basically, we can consider the nuclei as made of  some liquid(-ish) medium. During the collisions those nuclei break into smaller droplets and the kinematics of those droplets is determined by the properties of the medium.

Observations of the similar "ridge" in pp and p-ion collisions was much less expected. It suggests that some kind on hydrodynamic insight is also required for this type of processes.  Currently on the market there are some interesting proposals about what that medium could be. But the question is far from settled.